# How does a "pip --upgrade" know which files to replace and which to leave alone? Or does it delete and reinstall the entire package being upgraded?

Tags: python, pip

Pretty much what the title is asking. We had trouble lately where a `yum install python-urllib3` was getting an old version, and a `pip install -U urllib3` would update some of it, but not all of it, and a line in `poolmanager.py` would try to import a clas in `exceptions.py` that didn't exist (presumably because pip didn't realize it needed to update that file too). How does pip decide if a file needs to be upgraded or not?

Comment: It uninstalls any previous version before installing the newly obtained package of different version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are encountering is probably a conflict. try removing the package completely using `pip uninstall python-urllib3` and install it again. Also, please refer to the pip user guide about upgrading [Pip User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/)

> pip install --upgrade now has a --upgrade-strategy option which controls how pip handles upgrading of dependencies. There are 2 upgrade strategies supported:

- **eager**: upgrades all dependencies regardless of whether they still satisfy the new parent requirements
- **only-if-needed**: upgrades a dependency only if it does not satisfy the new parent requirements

The default strategy was `only-if-needed` and they changed it from versions `>=10.0`